# How to fix 'path.inShadow is not a function', when transpiling code using grunt/babel

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, babeljs, babel-cli

Transpiling javascript code using babel-cli via grunt.  Seeing error "path.inShadow is not a function" when transpiling first javascript file containing a class definition.

I believe that I have fully updated node and all of the packages (I'm new to the node ecosystem, so perhaps I'm missing something here).

Here's the snippet showing my dev dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compress": "^1.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^2.0.3",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-rename": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^4.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.1.0"
  }
```

I believe that my installis current because:

- npm install does nothing
- npm outdated shows nothing
- npm prune does nothing

node version is 10.15.0.

On a Mac in case that's relevant

Transpilation aborts with the error message:

> Warning: path.inShadow is not a function Use --force to continue.

It appears to be compiling a javascript file containing a class definition at the time, none of the preceding files that are successfully transpiled contain such definitions.

Comment: Perhaps try installing [babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes) and add `"plugins": ["transform-es2015-classes"]` to your `.babelrc` file.

Comment: @RobC -- thanks for responding.    What you suggested didn't work, but using the more recent @babel/plugin-transform-classes has changed the error.

Comment: @RobC -- just to close the loop.  Resolving unrelated error solved all my problems (well, the babel-related ones, anyway).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Following @RobC's suggestion.  Here's the answer:

1. Install `@babel/plugin-transform-classes`
2. and add`"plugins": [ "@babel/plugin-transform-classes" ]` to *.babelrc*.

Problem solved.